# Why "pip3 install virtualenvwrapper-win" command is not working in cmd?

Tags: python, web, cmd, web-deployment, django-errors

```
pip3 install virtualenvwrapper-win
```

Command is not working while setting up environment for Django development. It's showing syntax error.

Comment: Can you share the error?

Comment: already shared that it is saying 'pip3' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing " py -m pip install virtualenvwrapper-win " and comment the result.

Comment: It is showing the message  <  Requirement already satisfied: virtualenvwrapper-win in e:\lib\site-packages (1.2.5)
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in e:\lib\site-packages (from virtualenvwrapper-win) (16.0.0) >

Comment: So it's saying that it's already installed? try using 'import virtualenvwrapper-win' in your code and see if it works

Comment: It is saying that 'import' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.